# Value is required after -x (--tabs)

Tags: linux, man, less, tabs

I try to use "man command" but terminal gives me this output "Value is required after -x (--tabs)". What is this?

Comment: What is the _exact_ command you're giving when you get that error message?

Comment: for example: man less   then output  "Value is required after -x (--tabs)"

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from the `less` pager that is used by default to paginate `man` pages - perhaps because of an environment variable setting such as `LESS=-x`. What happens if you type `LESS= man less` ?

Comment: while i typed man less i gave that error

Comment: Thanks guys it worked                                                                                                     "export LESS=man less

Comment: @miladiiism That's a nonsensical command that happens to resolve your issue by accident. It would be better to know where you originally set `LESS` to `-x` and then fix that.